# NUnit.Extensions.Asp.DoctypeDtdException: Problem with DOCTYPE DTD:

Tags: nunit

I am using NUnitAsp for testing ASP.NET 2.0 pages.  I am getting DoctypeDtdException.
NUnit.Extensions.Asp.DoctypeDtdException: Problem with DOCTYPE DTD:   Your DOCTYPE is probably incorrect.  If you're not sure what DOCTYPE should be, user , Visual Studio .NET's default.

My page using Visual Studio 2008 default doctype.

When use only  it works fine.

I am desperately looking for the solution.

help is highly appreciated.

Comment: When I tried this solution on my person machine it works.  It is throwing exception only at work place.  There may be some access issue there